# Is there a maximum fee per byte in satoshis?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

i have seen recent transactions with fees as low as 1.065 satoshis per byte.
and some transactions with fees as high as 500+ satoshis per byte.

so i would like to know is there maximum fee ? in satoshis per byte ?

can i do transaction of 100 btc with setting 99 btc as fee ? (with only 1 input and 1 output. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, there is no maximum limit for the fee. The fee is simply the difference between the sum of the input values and the sum of the output values, so if you wanted to donate 99 BTC to the miners there is nothing stopping you - no idea why you'd want to donate an entire house though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core has a hard limit for what it considers to be an absurdly high fee.

That limit is 0.1 BTC Any transaction that pays more than 0.1 BTC in transaction fees, regardless of the fee rate, will be rejected with this error `256: absurdly-high-fee` . It is not consensus invalid, it is just non-standard.

Comment: This isn't correct.  Absurdly-high-fees are _not_ non-standard.   The wallet/rpc interface will reject them unless given an argument to override, but on the network they're be relayed and mined just fine.

Comment: @G.Maxwell Actually that's Andrew answer on https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2692430.0

Comment: That doesn't make it any less incorrect.

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/2949  here is where the functionality was introduced

Comment: so its just limitation in bitcoin-core, what if i create raw transaction broadcast it to the   bitcoin network using other services., then it will be relayed.

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 1):

At the moment no more than 17662867.32455670 BTC exist. A transaction can't be smaller than 63 bytes so the "maximum feerate" would be 28036297340566.19 satoshi per byte and increasing with each block.